# Deferred test cleanup behaves differently based on where I invoke it

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I've got a test that follows the following structure:

```
var testInstance aetest.Instance // initialized by a TestMain

TestThing(t *testing.T) {
    defer cleanupGoogleDatastore(t, testInstance)

    // insert basic test fixtures

    // insert some new records here

    // test assertions, etc.
}
```

The `cleanupGoogleDatastore` method just runs a datastore Query for all entities of a specific entity kind, and then deletes them one by one. Source here:

```
func cleanupGoogleDatastore(t *testing.T, testInstance aetest.Instance) {
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Order")
    ctx := GetContext(t, testInstance)
    scanner := q.Run(ctx)
    for {
        var o model.Order
        key, err := scanner.Next(&o)
        if err == datastore.Done {
            return
        }
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
        err = datastore.Delete(ctx, key)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that records inserted after the "basic test fixtures" aren't deleted by this deferred cleanup statement.

If I change this test function to instead look like the following:

```
var testInstance aetest.Instance // initialized by a TestMain  

TestThing(t *testing.T) {
    defer cleanupGoogleDatastore(t, testInstance)

    // insert basic test fixtures

    // insert some new records here

    defer cleanupGoogleDatastore(t, testInstance)
    // note that I have to call it TWICE - just moving it here is not enough.

    // test assertions, etc.
}
```

*then* the newly created records are also deleted at the end of the test. My understanding was that `deferred` functions are just called at the end of the original function scope, which would imply that the query wouldn't be constructed and run until the end of the test, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. It seems like the query is being constructed *when the defer statement is called* and then executed at the end of the test.

I've tried moving `cleanupGoogleDatastore` into a closure (e.g. `defer func() { cleanupGoogleDatastore(t, testInstance }()` and that didn't change anything.

I suspect that somehow this is a case of the function arguments being evaluated at the point where I call defer instead of when the function is invoked, but since both `t` and `testInstance` are pointers rather than direct values I'm not sure how that could be happening. There's no other evidence that the two values have changed. Printing out the fields of both structs at the different logical evaluation points doesn't reveal anything new.

What's going on here?

Comment: Is that the actual signature of your cleanup function or are you passing some arguments to it?

Comment: Or is it a method defined on a non pointer value?

Comment: @mkopriva that is not the actual signature. The actual signature takes a *testing.T and an aetest.Instance. I've updated the code example to more accurately reflect the actual code.

Comment: What @mkopriva is hinting at is that function arguments are determined at the point of `defer` instead of when executed. Everything is pass-by-value, so a copy is made at the point of `defer` for when it finally executes. (Don't confuse a pointer though, the pointer value is copied, but it still points to the same thing which would reflect changes) See example for some gotchas. https://play.golang.org/p/2LoG_90OiSM

Comment: ... yeah, what @RayfenWindspear said.

Comment: @Venantius a simple fix for this would be to wrap the call to the cleanup function into a closure, that way the args get evaluated at the time the deferred function is executed. `defer func() { cleanup(arg1, arg2) }()`

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a closure and that didn't seem to fix it. `defer func() { cleanupGoogleDatastore(t, testInstance) }()` - am I missing something?

Comment: Also, t is a pointer not a value, and as far as I know aetest.Instance is _also_ a pointer.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm unsure what's up.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that the values of the arguments to the function are different at the two different places at which you've tried calling it. Did you try printing out the values?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here's the internal `instance` type that implements `aetest.Instance`. https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/aetest/instance_vm.go#L55

Comment: @AndySchweig tried printing out the values; they're identical.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a deliberate property of the local App Engine Datastore stub, which returns weakly consistent queries by default. I was able to resolve this by changing the code for `cleanupGoogleDatastore` to rely on an ancestor query, which successfully found and then deleted all of the entities. An alternative approach would have been to set aetest.Instance to be strongly consistent, but I didn't want to force strongly consistent behavior on all of my tests - just this one.